# Honeywell Dead Reckoning Module GPS Problems

Tags: gps, nmea, dead-reckoning

I'm currently trying to connect a Honeywell DRM4000L to a GPS module. The DRM is a dead-reckoning device which takes a GPS input and outputs the location by serial. Currently, I have a GS407 GPS module connected to the DRM. Every time I try the GPS pass-through function on the DRM, I get gibberish output.

I also have an FTDI cable connected to the GPS and I'm getting the correct NMEA data. The data coming in from the GPS is all formatted correctly when connected directly to the computer. The DRM data is also coming in correctly, but it doesn't see an NMEA data stream and thus does not initialize with the GPS data. It only has track information based off of the inertial sensors.

The GPS is set to 9600 baud and the DRM host port is set to 9600, so the DRM should be seeing all the correct GPS data. The baud rate from the DRM to the computer is also 9600.

Is anyone seeing anything that I'm not seeing? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to [Electronics StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks. I did that now.

Comment: Moved to Electronics StackExchange.
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95153/honeywell-dead-reckoning-module-gps-problems

Comment: Voting to close/delete.  This question has already been moved to another StackExchange site.

Comment: @Brad - I will close it as soon as I can. StackExchange doesn't let me mark the question as answered until another 23 hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved to Electronics StackExchange. The problem was that the DRM is using RS-232 while the GPS is using TTL, thus causing the incompatibility between the two modules. A MAX3232 or MAX232 is used to convert these voltages.

Link to complete post:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/95153/honeywell-dead-reckoning-module-gps-problems